# How to present percentage graphically in Excel?

Tags: conditional-formatting, excel-2016

I am working on a customer satisfaction questionnaire and would like to present the results graphically, something like in the picture below:

[image]

A click on 0% should automatically colour a cell in red, 25% should be presented in orange, 50% are highlighted in yellow, etc.

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Many thanks and loads of coffee to you all!

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, this is very simple.

Assuming you know how to associate the value of the option group to a cell, add conditional formatting to each cell (that is underneath the option button ) that sets its background color to the appropriate color based on the value of the associated cell.

For example...
[image: Conditional formatting needed to color a cell based on a checkbox]

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your answer and your time! Unfortunately, I don't know how to associate the value of the option group to a cell. I would really be happy if you could help me as I am really lost here.

Comment: Sam, you would ask that separately, and only after researching it yourself. It's really basic - you'll figure it out if you look. Also, read the community guidelines when you have time. Stacking questions together erodes the value of the community and makes it look like you're offloading the whole job to the community.

Comment: I'd also add that using an option group in Excel without knowing how to associate it with a cell is like buying clothes that don't fit.